# Argument of type '[number, ...Type]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have an event emitter that has another emitter inside like this:

```
export class ShardedGateway extends EventEmitter<ShardedGatewayEvents> {
  shards: Record<number, Gateway> = {};
  // ...
}
```

And I'm trying to make the `ShardedGateway` emit the event with the id. So I modified the `Event#on` function:

```
  on<K extends keyof ShardedGatewayEvents>(
    eventName: K,
    listener: (...args: ShardedGatewayEvents[K]) => void,
  ): this;
```

And implemented the code:

```
      Object.entries(this.shards).forEach(([shardID, shard]) => {
        shard.on(eventName, (...args) => {
          listener(Number(shardID), ...args);
        });
      });
```

Also made a type for it:

```
export type ShardedGatewayEvents = {
  [K in keyof GatewayEvents]: [number, ...GatewayEvents[K]];
};
```

[I made a small reproducible code in here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAcQIZhgdyRAogNxgOzAGc4BeOAb1DjgAksBBAJQBUAhRlgfQYGEBpAFxwA2gF0A3NThMsvAPIA5RXJbDxUkDQCSigGoMAMtoAiXAMpZz57UvWTpvQ-Msn1+AK4BbAEYwATgA0cD4A9qEANjBI+MFhkdH4DlpwAPSpcAB02aAAvqCgkLBw5gAWSP4AJjCVyKgY2HiEJORUKSL8cACW+HAA1jAQoQBmiCjomLgExGLu3n5BWdl1E43TRB1iybmaoOlwvKFQXTVww-6hXnClYGBQRILp1fihmRExlakAHqkwTWAAAQATJkAAxg1JeUKVTLEUAAY3eRBIU0IWC8XVuAQAPFg4DAvqh8JUSEwYPDQlVsUQwP4egBzYIefB9F5ofDiAB8nMo0lC+GxnQJRJJ-UGIzgWE5AAo-tNFEgvDBhPxghEujSCAFhNLspkKvSHpLNgBKMg8nChLqVE3CMClDW8lI0fZES7wGkeYbDIjSGj+GBgDz+Xr2jXSfIgSN7DI0OPxhMJljQU5ywj4jFY-zXAIwBFIkgrBr4wkEUWosDozGofzYouTf5EHltF0ZN1KuD08bFrpeKBRJWEFBdfl5AogfaJqfTpMpyr4-4Z6sBHMB-NIZElcpVGr1iAlkUo-5VrPYsoVaq1bsN9bN6REbck4RkilUzy+ALBPc81o7cetpZMn-OB+UFA8yxIAYhlGc8dyveob2aGU-QXeVFWVOBVRQ9VNXwAIAH4dT1A0jVgy89wrDZ+DEM1SAtK1KkCaRbTgMMSBbOMulGaUcKJAIzQ4+N5B8AArckwEyaY6RgIhpTYzIHwvIgTUyYZKSwJB4VKaVpRERSqlMYJ9MqGjzSdadjMyflZX+BUlWCXVshI2i72dKdeK1fxpUUeYAmlYzTBNYJiP8Q0TU0adcnClCaCiiK40jeMAyDENWIdX0UkjXIgA)

But on the listener function argument TypeScript says `Argument of type '[number, ...GatewayEvents[K]]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ShardedGatewayEvents[K]'.`

I had no idea to achieve this in other way, but for sure it should work with no problem.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. Also, you might find [this](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe) article useful

Comment: Could you share a link to typescript playground?

Comment: @Nullndr I just posted a link that reproduces this error.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I checked the link and it actually works! But I think this kinda creates a mess(like it makes code too long)

Comment: @Helloyunho you just need to overload `on` listener. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/weBneN)